# How can I get the html5 audio's duration time

Tags: html, audio, duration

I have a html5 `<audio>` tag in page, but how can I know its duration time?

```
<audio controls="">
    <source src="p4.2.mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 31):

**2020 solution:**

You will get `undefined` or `NaN` (not a number) when the audio metadata isn't loaded yet. Therefore some people suggested to use `onloadedmetadata` to make sure the metadata of the audio file is fetched first. Also, what most people didn't mention is that you have to target the first index of the audio DOM element with `[0]` like this:

-- Vanilla Javascript:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio-1');
audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  alert(audio.duration);
};
```

If this won't work try this, however not so reliable and dependent on users connection:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio-1');
    console.log("audio", audio.duration);
}, 100);
```

-- JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var audio = $("#audio-1")[0];
   $("#audio-1").on("loadedmetadata", function() {
       alert(audio.duration);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Since when was "$("#audio-1")[0];" Vanilla Javascript? Both of your examples are jQuery ones - not sure you understand the difference. Vanilla would be "document.getElementById('audio-1');" instead here.

Comment: @RichardEdwards Thanks for pointing that out. I mainly used JQuery at the time I wrote this answer before I completely switched to Vanilla JS and didn't notice this typo.

Answer (score 17):

```
var au = document.createElement('audio');
au.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function(){
    au.setAttribute('data-time',au.duration);
},false);
```

Answer (score 11):

In a comment above, it was mentioned that the solution is to bind an event handle to the event loadedmetadata. This is how I did that -

```
audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  alert(audio.duration);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with loading the duration in a React component so following @AlexioVay's solution, here is an answer if you're using React:

This assumes you are using a `ref` for your audio component class which you will need to target the `audio` elements for your play/pause handler(s).

`<audio />` element:

```
<audio ref={audio => { this.audio = audio }} src={this.props.src} preload="auto" />
```

Then in your `componentDidMount()`:

```
componentDidMount() {

    const audio = this.audio

    audio.onloadedmetadata = () => {
        console.log(audio.duration)
        this.setState({
           duration: this.formatTime(audio.duration.toFixed(0))
        })
    }
}
```

And finally the `formatTime()` function:

```js
formatTime(seconds) {
    const h = Math.floor(seconds / 3600)
    const m = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60)
    const s = seconds % 60
    return [h, m > 9 ? m : h ? '0' + m : m || '0', s > 9 ? s : '0' + s]
        .filter(a => a)
        .join(':')
}
```

With this, the duration in `h:mm:ss` format will display as soon as the audio src data is loaded. Sweetness.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning me. Can you also provide your solution for React hooks?

Answer (score 1):

I used "canplaythrough" event to get the track duration. I have a case where I have two players, and I want to stop the second player 2 seconds before the first one is complete.

```
$('#' + _currentPlayerID).on("canplaythrough", function (e) {   
    var seconds = e.currentTarget.duration;    
    var trackmills = seconds * 1000;
    var subTimeout = trackmills - 2000; //2 seconds before end

    //console.log('seconds ' + seconds);
    //console.log('trackmills ' + trackmills);
    //console.log('subTimeout ' + subTimeout);

    //Stop playing before the end of thet track
    //clear this event in the Pause Event
    _player2TimeoutEvent = setTimeout(function () { pausePlayer2(); }, subTimeout);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `audioElement.duration`

Comment: No, it doesn't work, I tried:`var audio = $('#audio')[0]; console.log('audio', audio.duration);` but the result is `NaN`

Comment: This gives the correct duration (tested in Firefox), but only after loadedmetadata event has happened.

Comment: Seems to work when you use `setTimeout(function () { ... }, 10);` instead of executing it right away.

Comment: @AlexioVay is right about the timeout, the file needs to have a moment to load before it can be tested

Answer (score -1):

To obtain the end of reading it is necessary that 'loop = false' with the event 'onended'. If loop = true, onended does not work;)

To make a playlist, you have to set loop = false to use the 'onended' event in order to play the next song.

for the duration if your script is done correctly you can recover the duration anywhere. If the value of 'duration' is NaN the file is not found by the browser. If the value is 'Infinity' 'INF' it is a streaming, in this case, adds 1 mn compared to the reading time 'currentime'.
For * I.E it's crap. Currenttime may be greater than duration, in which case you do:
var duration = (this.currentime> this.duration)? this.currenttime: this.duration;

That's (O_ °)

Answer (score -2):

it's better to use the  event like this ...

```
ObjectAudio.onprogress  =function(){
    if(this.buffered.length){
    var itimeend = (this.buffered.length>1)? this.buffered.end(this.buffered.length-1):this.buffered.end(0);
    ....
        Your code here.......
    }
}
```