# How to seek with AudioContext

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I would like to create buttons that will play next/prev song on click, but they should seek the music on long press.

I did manage to change songs, but I couldn't find the seek methods. Also how to make it play from beginning?

And is there a way to determine how much have passed since the beginning of the song? I found that buffer have duration, but no sing of actual play time.

At init:

```
context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)()
```

To play song:

```
var buffer = song.buffer
var source = context.createBufferSource()
source.buffer = song.buffer
source.connect(analysers.main)
source.start(0, offset || 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess, you should use `AudioBufferNode` (it has ability to do seek) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start

Also, this wrapper might be usefull - https://github.com/eipark/buffaudio

Comment: Could you please answer the second part of question too? The one about how far in song we are? In percents or something...

Comment: Guess, `AudiBufferNode` has `duration` property. You can try to use it.
Also, this could be useful a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203773/how-can-i-get-the-html5-audios-duration-time

Comment: This is incorrect, `AudioBufferSourceNode` cannot seek (you can't call `start` more than once).

Comment: This is incorrect. There is no way to seek or restart an AudioBufferNode. All it can do is suspend/resume and loop. You would need to create a new buffer node to seek.

Answer (score 1):

Use **taphold** API to acheive the long press Event.

```
$(function(){
  $( "your element" ).bind( "taphold", tapholdHandler );

  function tapholdHandler( event ){
   /*write your code here for seek forward */

  }
});
```

**Use JQuery Timer**

```
var mousedowntime;
    var presstime;
    $("button[id$='" + buttonID + "']").mousedown(function() {
        var d = new Date();
        mousedowntime = d.getTime();
    });
    $("button[id$='" + buttonID + "']").mouseup(function() {
        var d = new Date();
        presstime = d.getTime() - mousedowntime;
        if (presstime > 999/*You can decide the time*/) {
            //Do_Action_Long_Press_Event();
        }
        else {
            //Do_Action_Click_Event();
        }
    });
```

**To Play from Beginning**

```
function beginAudio(){
            audio.trigger('pause');
            audio.prop("currentTime",audio.prop("currentTime")-audio.prop("currentTime"));
            audio.trigger('play');
        }
```

or set current time to zero and then play.

**For Forward and Backward use this**

```
audio.prop("currentTime",audio.prop("currentTime")-5);// 5 secs backward
audio.prop("currentTime",audio.prop("currentTime")+5);// 5 secs forward
```

Comment: I dont have audio variable, I have context variable (typeof AudioContext). And no jQuery. And the hold to seek ain't the problem the seeking is, and the fact, that audiocontext start counting currentTime since it is created and don't stop on when the sound does

Comment: can you show your original code for audio context and also for `play next/prev song on click song` ..