# How to update the value of a html tag in a loop without overriding previous rounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have a list of url of some tracks. I want to show the duration of each track in a html list. I could manage to take the duration value from a function but the problem is in each round of the loop it overrides the given tag with the new value taken from duration function. So the whole list gets updated over and over.

```js
var src1, src2, src3, trackArray;
src1 = "https://goo.gl/o4nxfq";
src2 = "https://goo.gl/wc1pgB";
src3 = "https://goo.gl/25uOY6";
trackArray = [src1, src2, src3];
function initAudioPlayer(){
 $.each(trackArray, function( index, value ) {
   $(".panel").append(
     "<li>Track #"+ index +" >> <span class='due'></span></li>"
    );
    getDuration(value, ".due");
 });
}

function getDuration(src, destination) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    $(audio).on("loadedmetadata", function(){
        $(destination).html(audio.duration);
        
    });
    audio.src = src;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    initAudioPlayer();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="panel"></ul>
```

As you can see it show the value of the last round of loop for all `li` tags. 
Any idea fix it so it will show the real values in the list?

Comment: give each span a UNIQUE class or id or something - then use that in the "destination" parameter

Comment: Ya becasue `".due"` is matching all...  I'd use index instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each span a unique class for example

In this example, instead of .due, it'll be .due0, .due1, ...

in case you are using class name .due for styling, each span will also have the class `due` as well as `due#`

```
function initAudioPlayer(){
    $.each(trackArray, function( index, value ) {
        $(".panel").append(
            "<li>Track #"+ index +" >> <span class='due due"+index+"'></span></li>"
        );
        getDuration(value, ".due"+index);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing `.due`, you are targeting all elements with class `due`. You should pass `index` too, e.g:

```js
var src1, src2, src3, trackArray;
src1 = "https://goo.gl/o4nxfq";
src2 = "https://goo.gl/wc1pgB";
src3 = "https://goo.gl/25uOY6";
trackArray = [src1, src2, src3];
function initAudioPlayer(){
 $.each(trackArray, function( index, value ) {
   $(".panel").append(
     "<li>Track #"+ index +" >> <span class='due'></span></li>"
    );
    getDuration(value, ".due", index);
 });
}

function getDuration(src, destination, index) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    $(audio).on("loadedmetadata", function(){
        $(destination).eq(index).html(this.duration);
        
    });
    audio.src = src;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    initAudioPlayer();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="panel"></ul>
```

```js
var src1, src2, src3, trackArray;
src1 = "https://goo.gl/o4nxfq";
src2 = "https://goo.gl/wc1pgB";
src3 = "https://goo.gl/25uOY6";
trackArray = [src1, src2, src3];
function initAudioPlayer(){
 $.each(trackArray, function( index, value ) {
   $(".panel").append(
     "<li>Track #"+ index +" >> <span class='due'></span></li>"
    );
    getDuration(value, ".due");
 });
}

function getDuration(src, destination) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    $(audio).on("loadedmetadata", function(){
        $(destination).html(audio.duration);
        
    });
    audio.src = src;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    initAudioPlayer();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="panel"></ul>
```