# How to get audio file name, size, local path, total time duration using input type file in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How to get audio file name, size, local path, total time duration, file extension using input type file? I am using Angular 2. I am unable to get time duration and local file path.

Once I upload audio file it should go to server with audio file duration. I want to achieve this requirement using only typescript, JavaScript, HTML, Angular 2, without using any third party library.

If any one have idea please let me know. Some code:

html file

```
     <input  type="file"  name="file" id="file" accept="audio/*"  (change)="doBrowse($event)"  multiple/>  

      <button class="btn btn_save" type="button" name="files" (click)="uploadAudio($event)"  [disabled]="disableUploadButton">
                               Upload
                            </button>
```

Ts file :

```
    import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { PostService } from '../../post.service';
    import { AppComponent } from '../../app.component';
    import { UploadAudioFile } from '../../admin';

    const uploadURL = '/upload';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-audiofileupload',
      templateUrl: './audiofileupload.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./audiofileupload.component.css']
    })
    export class AudiofileuploadComponent implements OnInit {

      list_page=true;

      formData:any;
       headers:any;
       options:any;
      file:any;
      file_array=[];
      fileName_array=[];
      fileList:FileList[];
      path:any;
      fullPath:any;
      fullPath_array=[];
      slectHospital:any;
      slectDepartment:any;
      selectDoctor:any;

      errorMessage;
      localUrl: any[];
      fileReader: any;
      sourceJson:any;
      getPath:any;
    fileLength:any;
    fileName:any[];
    uploadFiles:any;
    addUploadFiles:any;





        constructor(private postservice: PostService) {
         }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.slectHospital="";
        this.slectDepartment="";
        this.selectDoctor="";
      }


      doBrowse(event){

     if(!this.slectHospital){
     alert("Please Select Hospital ");
       return false;
     }

     if(!this.slectDepartment) {
       alert("Please Select Department ");   
       return false;
     } 

     if(!this.selectDoctor) {
      alert("Please Select Doctor");
       return false;
     }

    alert("hospital data :"+this.slectHospital+ ", Dept Data :"+this.slectDepartment+" , hospital data :"+this.slectHospital);
    console.log(JSON.stringify("hospital data :"+this.slectHospital+ ", Dept Data :"+this.slectDepartment+" , hospital data :"+this.slectHospital));

    this.fileList= event.target.files;
    this.fileLength=this.fileList.length;


    alert(" length :"+(JSON.stringify(this.fileList.length)));


    if(this.fileList &&  this.fileList.length > 0) {
      alert("Inside if block ======== ");
      this.file= this.fileList[0];


      this.formData=new FormData();
        this.path="file://C:/Users/Pawananjay.r/Music/";
        for (let i=0; i < this.fileList.length; i++) {
        this.file_array[i]=this.fileList[i];
        this.fileName_array[i]=this.file_array[i].name;
        this.fullPath_array[i]=this.path+this.file_array[i].name;
       alert(+i+"  in side loop : "+this.fileName_array[i] +","+this.fullPath_array[i]);
         }

       this.formData.append('uploadFile_key', this.fileName);

        alert("file name :"+(JSON.stringify(this.file.name)));
        console.log(JSON.stringify("File Name:"+this.file.name));



        this.headers=new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');


        alert("Header Accept:"+this.headers.get("Accept") +"--Header  Content Type : "+this.headers.get("Content-Type"));
        console.log(JSON.stringify("Header Accept:"+this.headers.get("Accept") +"--Header  Content Type : "+this.headers.get("Content-Type")));

        this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
        alert("option value  :"+(JSON.stringify(this.options)));
        console.log(JSON.stringify("option value :"+this.options));
    console.log(JSON.stringify("localUrl :"+this.localUrl));
    var path1 = (window.URL).createObjectURL(this.file);
    console.log('path url :',path1);
    alert("path url : "+path1);
    }
    }

    uploadAudio(event){

      this.fileList= event.target.files;
      alert("Audio File uploaded  start");

      this.path="file://C:/Users/Pawananjay.r/Music/";
      this.fullPath=this.path+this.fileName;
    console.log(JSON.stringify("length :"+(JSON.stringify(this.fileLength))));
    console.log(JSON.stringify("Full Path :"+this.fullPath));

    if(this.fileLength > 0 && this.fileLength!=-1 && this.fileName_array.length>0) {

      for (let i=0; i < this.fileLength; i++) {
      alert(this.fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file_array[i]));

      alert( this.fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.fileList[0]));


       this.file_array[i]=this.fileList[i];
    alert(+i+"in side loop : "+this.file_array[i].name);
    this.fullPath_array[i]=this.path+this.file_array[i].name;
    alert("in side loop 2 :"+this.fullPath_array[i]);

    alert("audio size : "+(this.file_array[i].size)/(1024*1024));
    alert("file  type : "+this.file_array[i].type);
    alert("File extension : "+this.file_array[i].name.substring(this.file_array[i].name.lastIndexOf('.'), this.file_array[i].name.length) || this.file_array[i].name);

    alert("audio duration : "+this.file_array[i].duration);    

      }
    alert("File Name Array : "+this.fileName_array);
    alert("Full Path array :"+this.fullPath_array);

    console.log(JSON.stringify("length :"+(JSON.stringify(this.fileLength))));
    console.log(JSON.stringify("File Name Array :"+(JSON.stringify(this.fileName_array))));
    console.log(JSON.stringify("Full Path array :"+this.fullPath_array));


    alert("Audio File uploaded successfully end ");

    this.postservice.uploadAudioFiles()
    .subscribe(
      result=> this.uploadFiles = result,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
    );
    }else{
      alert("Please browse file ! ");
      }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get audio.duration value by a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647536/how-to-get-audio-duration-value-by-a-function)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.