# How to get audio.duration from a <audio> player and save it to a div on a click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mp3, html5-audio

I've been looking for a way to get the duration of a MP3 file that's hosted remotely and I found answer from another question ([How can I get the html5 audio's duration time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203773/how-can-i-get-the-html5-audios-duration-time)) and now I'm trying to see if I make it work.

I'm hung up this part:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var audio = $("#audio-1")[0];
     $("#audio-1").on("loadedmetadata", function() {
        alert(audio.duration);
     }); 
  });
```

What that code does is getting the duration of a MP3 file and display it in the console. What I'm trying to do get the duration of the MP3 file when you click on a button and save that data into a ''.

Here's my code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var audio = $("#audio-1")[0];
  $("#click").on("click", function() {
   $("#audio-1").on("loadedmetadata", function() {
   $(".duration").data{(audio.duration)};
   }); 
  });
});
```

```css
.duration {height:20px;border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio-1" src="https://media.acast.com/dth/weekinreviewfortheweekof6-21-21-dth/media.mp3" preload="metadata"></audio>

Duration:
<div class="duration"></div>

<button id="click">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function() {
       var audio = $("#audio-1")[0];
      
            $("#duration").html(audio.duration);
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>First Pen</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div id="duration"></div>

<button id="btn">Click</button>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio-1" src="https://media.acast.com/dth/weekinreviewfortheweekof6-21-21-dth/media.mp3" preload="metadata"></audio>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I did this and it worked.

Comment: https://codepen.io/easnamir/pen/wvdwbBo check this pen , it runs fine

Comment: Thank you, it works! I've been looking for years on how to solve this problem and now I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.innerText` instead of `.data`.

Also, your code is throwing an error because of the curly braces on the `.data` line:

```js
$(".duration").data{(audio.duration)};
```

If you were to use the `.data` call, it should have regular braces: `.data("duration", audio.duration)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var audio = $("#audio-1")[0];
  $("#click").on("click", function() {
    $("#audio-1").on("loadedmetadata", function() {
      $(".duration").innerText(audio.duration);
    }); 
  });
});
```

```css
.duration {height:20px;border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio-1" src="https://media.acast.com/dth/weekinreviewfortheweekof6-21-21-dth/media.mp3" preload="metadata"></audio>

Duration:
<div class="duration"></div>

<button id="click">Click</button>
```