# HTML audio duration not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Upong calling audioElement.duraion returns infinite in chromium based browsers but works find in firefox. The song is stored locally in the same directory.

```
console.log("Welcome to Spotify | clone");
let songIndex = 0;
const masterPlay = document.getElementById("masterPlay");
const progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
const gif = document.getElementById("gif");
const audioElement=document.getElementById("song")

// let audioElement=new Audio('./1.mp3')
// Handeling play pause and click
masterPlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (audioElement.paused || audioElement.currentTime <= 0) {
        audioElement.play();
        masterPlay.classList.remove("fa-circle-play");
        masterPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-pause");
        gif.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    else {
        audioElement.pause();
        masterPlay.classList.remove("fa-circle-pause");
        masterPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-play");
        gif.style.opacity = 0;

    }
});

//EventListeners
audioElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
    progress = ((audioElement.currentTime / audioElement.duration) * 100);
    progressBar.value = progress;
    console.log(audioElement.currentTime)
});
```

Expectations:

It returns the duration of the autio track.

What I tried:

- Different browsers. (Works fine on firefox based browsers.)
- Different song. (I found that some songs don't work on chrome but on firefox everything works.)
- Tried using HTML audio element. (The problem persists)
- Tried using JS audio(). (The problem still exists)

Comment: *If the element's media doesn't have a known duration—such as for live media streams—the value of duration is +Infinity* - is it a stream?

Comment: It is a media from NCS called Mortals and it's around 3:50 sec and is stored in the same folder as the project files. Firefox works fine but every chromium based browser show problem

Comment: So `progress` is `0` every time in chrome?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is always 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the html5 audio's duration time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203773/how-can-i-get-the-html5-audios-duration-time)

Comment: Are you running this from a web server or from the filesystem? I will suggest using a web server could help.

Comment: The problem is faced on chromium based browsers. I searched google but got no answer I read 2 stackoverflow threads too but I can't seem to get it working

Comment: @Yogi Okay upon further testing some songs are not working but others are. On firefox everything is working but the things is why?

Comment: The problem seems specific to your system.  When I run your code in Chrome it works as expected with various mp3 files.  I've not seen any documentation or posts about duration not working in Chrome.

Comment: I also got it working but for some songs it doesn't work while upon changing currentTime it restets to 0 for some reason on chrome

Comment: see related question: [HTML5 Audio Tag Showing Wrong Duration of MP3 in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711488/html5-audio-tag-showing-wrong-duration-of-mp3-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day I found out that it was a bug with VS code Live Preview extension from Microsoft

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).